# Equivalent of CSS multiple selector in XPath

Tags: css, xml, xpath, css-selectors

Is there some kind of CSS multiple selector (comma) in XPath, so I could find fetch, say, `//img` and `//*[@background]` elements in one query?

Comment: [Tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xpathbar.php) Is this what you're looking for ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is an `or` operator (`|`) in XPath:

```
//img|//*[@background]
```

Comment: Oh, that was easy. Thanks! :)

Comment: unlike css comma it'd select either one correct? css comma would select both if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Use `|`, e.g.: `//img | //*[@background]`

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the "union" operator `|` which exists in XPath 1.0 and 2.0 there is also [the "comma" operator](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#construct_seq) `,` in XPath 2.0 to form a sequence of items e.g. `//img, //*[@background]`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is the pipe (`|`).

```
//img | //*[@background]
```